# java jigsaw extend jar library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to separate a project of mine into Jigsaw Modules. One pain point has been to use .jar libraries in multiple modules and extend their functionality in some of them.

To be more concrete, I am using minimal-json-0.9.1.jar via "requires transitive minimal.json" in a module-info.java file and I set the module to be on the modulepath in eclipse.
I then created this interface:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;

public interface JsonSerializable {

  JsonObject toJson();

}
```

Note that JsonObject comes from the minimal.json library.

Now I get a warning message in eclipse: "The type JsonObject is not exported from this module". How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**: Do not `transitive`ly rely on an *automatic-module* and change your module-descriptor to make use of

```
requires minimal.json;
```

**Explanation**: While including the `transitive` modifier, an *implied readability* is expressed by the `requires` clause. This means that any module that depends upon your module [`requires your.module`] will also be able to read the `minimal.json` module.

The warning from eclipse seems to be highlighting the same point that the use of `JsonObject` in any further module that requires your module would not be because your module have explicitly exported [`exports some.package;`] the package including the class, rather because of the transitive dependency.

Comment: And when I thought, it might not be a big task to migrate [the library](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) to support Java9. Seems like its still supporting 1.5 :|

Comment: I changed it to just `requires minimal.json` but the warning didn't go away...
and do I not want the implied readability?
Because I'm trying to use the JsonSerializable interface and therefore JsonObject outside of this module and I thought that's what the readability meant.

Comment: @EzPizza Seems more like a [bug with eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=532724) then, could you try updating the IDE and then verify the same.

Comment: I already checked for updates, but apparently there are none. I guess I'm just not going to ignore the warning then :D I just wanted to check that my approach is not completely wrong.